# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type inet:

Tags: java, postgresql, ip-address, prepared-statement, inet

I'm trying to insert an ipaddress into a Postgres Table from a Java project.

```
String ipIns = "INSERT INTO trusted_domains(id, from_ip, to_ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(ipIns);
pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
pstmt.setObject(2, InetAddress.getByName(fromIP));
pstmt.setObject(3, InetAddress.getByName(toIP));
pstmt.execute();
```

I get an exception for this statement pstmt.setObject(2, InetAddress.getByName(fromIP));

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type inet:

Kindly help me on this exception

Thanks
--SD

Comment: I got it, its pstmt.setObject(2, fromIP, Types.OTHERS);

Thanks
--SD

Answer (score 1):

You have found it by now, but for the general public:

The [`inet` data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET) accepts IPv4 and IPv6 hosts and networks, not domain names.
Works:

```
SELECT '192.168.1.251'::inet
SELECT '123.45.67.89/32'::inet
SELECT '::ffff:10.4.3.2'::inet
SELECT '1234:ef8:345:ad:934:efff:aaa:d1f1/128'::inet
```

Doesn't work:

```
SELECT 'stackoverflow.com'::inet
```